# How are images resized in ImageDataGenerator

Tags: tensorflow, keras, image-resizing

In my understanding, when using tensorflow keras, we can flow data from directories using `ImageDataGenerator`. When the data is flowed in, they are resized to `target_size`. But how is this transformation done?

An example is this:

```
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
trainDir = 'train'
dataGen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1/255)
gen = dataGen.flow_from_directories(
  trainDir,
  batch_size=64,
  target_size=(150, 150),
  class_mode='binary'
)
```

Here, all the images from `trainDir` would be resized to 150x150. But how are they resized?

I've checked the [documentation on tensorflow ImageDataGenerator](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/preprocessing/image/ImageDataGenerator). It only says that `target_size` is "The dimensions to which all images found will be resized." But I didn't find an explanation on how the resizing is done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It uses the `interpolation` parameter when the `target_size` is different from the size of input image. The default interpolation method used is `nearest` but others are available to use as well.

Source: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/preprocessing/image/ImageDataGenerator

Answer (score 0):

The ImageDataGenerator has a parameter fill_mode. This parameter can be set as follows

```
One of {"constant", "nearest", "reflect" or "wrap"}. Default is 'nearest'. Points outside the boundaries of the input are filled according to the given mode:
'constant': kkkkkkkk|abcd|kkkkkkkk (cval=k)
'nearest': aaaaaaaa|abcd|dddddddd
'reflect': abcddcba|abcd|dcbaabcd
'wrap': abcdabcd|abcd|abcdabcd
frankly I have no idea what the above is intending to illustrate
```